# Trying to route each li element to a component that displays a detailed page of the item

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm fetching data from an endpoint and trying to create routes for each individual li element. It's currently rendering the data, but I'm having trouble going to a different page whenever I select the li  element.

Where can I set up the route for each element so that when I select li with the onClick method I can go to a completely different page that shows a component with the current data selected similar to an commerce website that displays all the items and goes to a detailed screen when selected? The previous list of sneakers shouldn't be visible when I go to a new page and should be an entire component on its own.

I've set up a route that has the path="/detailView/" component={DetailView} and have an onSelect() method that updates the state with the current li element selected using this.setState(state => ({name : entry.name})). this.props.history.push is commented out since it pushes a blank page without configuring the component.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7LB2.png) 
Currently how the page is being displayed.

```
class Api extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'https://yawndry-heroku.herokuapp.com/sneakers'

        fetch(url)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    data: result
                })
            })
    }


    onSelect(entry) {
        let path = entry.name


        console.log(entry.name)

        this.setState(state => ({
            name : path
        }))
        // this.props.history.push('/detailView/')
    }

    render() {

        const {data} = this.state
        const result = data.map((entry, index) => {
            return <h3>
                       <li key={index} onClick={() => this.onSelect(entry)} >{entry.name} {entry.condition}</li>
                       <Link to="/detailView/" onClick={() => this.onSelect(entry)}>More Details</Link> 
                    </h3>
        })




        return <Router>
                    <Route exact path="/detailView/" 
                            render={(props) => <DetailView {...props} name={this.state.name}/>} />
                    <ul>{result}</ul>

                </Router>
    }

export default withRouter(Api)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar thing where we send the user to a specific ticket page when clicking on the title. Here is how it is set up : 
we have a Link with a path and something that identifies the item

```
<Link to={`/detailView/id`} target={'_blank'}>
```

In the Router  :

```
<Route path="/detailView/:key"  component={DetailView} />
```

In the Component, I have a call to my API that retrieves the data :

```
componentDidMount() {
// Set title page
document.title = this.props.match.params.key;
//Retrieve the data
this.props.getAll(this.props.match.params.key)
}
```

This depends on where you get your data from, but then you can populate your component with your retrieved data, depending on what you put in your render.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Alicia. Thanks for trying to help :). It's not rendering the component properly this way unfortunately. I kind of need the new page to be within the history hierarchy so you can go back and forth. The way I've set up the routes might be completely wrong. Is there a way to isolate components so they can display content depending on which item has been has been selected? Currently its setup where both the results and the DetailView are being displayed on the same page.

Comment: I would like to help, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean ? For the history, if everything works properly, React-router should update it with your Link click. If you want separate components, you need to have your Router as a higher level wrap component for your app. To render one element only, look at [Switch](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md). This is mine :

Comment: `<Router >
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/error" component={Error419}/>
                <App>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
                        <Route exact path="/planning" component={Planning} />
                        <Route path="/ticket/:key"  component={Ticket} />
                    </Switch>
                </App>
            </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>`

Comment: Then in App, I have a div that renders a TopBar (that is always printed except on the Error419 page), and then `{this.props.children}`. That is my set up, and when i work on a link, the correct Ticket gets printed, so it should be able to work if you can identify your specific item with the `/id` in the Link component.